# How to get parent using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to further my understanding of traversing and correctly using `$(this)`.

I understand `$(this)` is used in reference to the context. However, say I have three items that are identical to each other (HTML-wise) and if a user clicks on an input, I want the events to not only happen for the item the user selected, but be able to access the parent element `".item"` as well. This way, I can hide other elements within `".item"` because, again, the context would be the `"input"` that the user clicked.

This is where I am confused. When a user clicks on the input (`$('input').on('click', doSomething);`), I am limited to the context of the input - nothing is inside the input, so I want to access other elements that are out of the input context.

I then try and use `$(this)` to say I only want THIS event to happen for THIS item only, not affecting ALL items.

Here is a code example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RSapL/19/)

I've tried researching this and I can't find much information on an instance like this so hopefully this could benefit others too. Feel free to make edits to the content / heading as I've tried to be as specific as possible.

Comment: [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: $(this).parent() ? http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: *"I've tried researching this and I can't find much information on an instance like this"* I'm sorry, but no. If you spend an hour (that's all it takes) reading [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com), you'll find the information you need.

Comment: Why don't you answer questions in the "Your Anwer" box? Thats what it is for. Comments can not be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

To get the immediate parent(s) of the element(s) in a jQuery set: [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent). (If your set has only one element, as `$(this)` will, that will give you that element's immediate parent.)

To find the closest element(s) to the elements(s) in a jQuery set matching a given selector, starting with the current element(s): [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest). (If your set has only one element, as `$(this)` will, that will give you the first element matching a selector starting with that one element, then looking at its parent, then *its* parent, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This should be your click-handler code :

```
function doSomething(event) {
    $(event.target).parent().find('ul').hide();
}
```